# Как отобразить сообщения об ошибках, используя jquery Validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation

Имеется следующий код для валидации инпутов:

```
$('.refresh').click(function() {
            $('.price-filter').validate({
                rules: {
                    price: {
                        required: true,
                        number: true
                    }
                },

                messages: {
                    price: {
                        required: "Поля ввода не должны быть пустыми",
                        number: "Введите цифры"
                    }
                },

                errorElement: "div",

                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    $('.error').insertAfter('.price-filter');
                },

                submitHandler: function() {
                    table.draw();
                }

            })
        });
```

На первый взгляд все настроено верно, однако сообщения об ошибках не выводятся. Как это исправить? Заранее спасибо.
Полный код находится здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/zu2yhmvx/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Самая главная ошибка в том, что валидируются формы, а не просто скелет из html. Потому что у представленного вами кода нет тега form и вы валидируете по клику содержимое дива.

я немного исправил ваш код для примера. И старайтесь не использовать одинаковые неймы на разных инпутах. 
Во-первых - плагин завалидирует только первый нашедшийся
Во вторых - при отправке данных вы получите одно значение - в вашем случае price, хотя вы забираете 2 разных поля "цена от" и "цена до".

К тому же вам не стоит валидацию навешивать на клик по кнопке - в самом плагине уже есть обработчик сабмита и вы его указали, поэтому вы фактически делаете лишнее действие.

Валидация этим плагином должна выглядеть примерно вот так

```
$('form').validate({
rules: {
  price_from: {
    required: true,
    number: true
  },
  price_to: {
    required: true,
    number: true
  }
},
messages: {
  price_from: {
    required: "Поля ввода не должны быть пустыми",
    number: "Введите цифры"
  },
  price_to: {
    required: "Поля ввода не должны быть пустыми",
    number: "Введите цифры"
  }
},
submitHandler: function() {
  alert('ok');
}
```

})

https://jsfiddle.net/zu2yhmvx/ - было
https://jsfiddle.net/wbh3em49/ - стало

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, помогло!

Comment: Тут есть кнопка, которая отмечает ответ как верный) Рад, что помог